# Is it a good/right practice to use Finally keyword to prevent the JVM from re-ordering?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, finally, try-finally

I just think of this question, and I have not found a similar question asked anywhere. I can close this one if there is a duplicate that I have not found.
Here is a simple example:

Assuming this is a multi-threading scenario, and in a writer thread, I would like to guarantee that I first write value A, and then write value B to a data structure.

```
  public void writeMethod(...) {
     try {
        writeValueA(...);
     } finally {
        writeValueB(...);
     }
  }
```

I know `finally` is useful for [exception handling and common for cleaning up resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html). But my question is, is it a good / right practice to use `finally` keyword as an explicit way to prevent JVM from reordering my code / instructions?

Comment: No, it is not helpful here. I do not know how your multiple threads would access this code, but if two threads accessed `writeMethod` in parallel, you might get `AABB`. But never will one thread call `B` before `A`, no matter whether you use the `finally` block or not. If `A` and `B` start a thread each internally, though, and `A` takes long, then that might result in out-of-order behavior, but the `finally` is not going to help you here. Maybe you could shed some light on how your threads are organized to get a more definitive answer.

Comment: what do you mean by JVM re-ordering your instructions?

Comment: @Jayanth I suppose he is thinking of this: [jls-17.4 Memory Model: ...This provides a great deal of freedom for the implementor to perform a myriad of code transformations, including the reordering of actions and removal of unnecessary synchronization.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)

Comment: Any reordering of instructions is such that the reordering is has no detectable effect within a single thread. In other words, the side effects of executing `writeValueB` then `writeValueA` *must be* the same as `writeValueA` then `writeValueB` for it even to be considered for reordering. So finally makes no difference in this code.

Comment: Definitely not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

The method

```
public void writeMethod(…) {
    try {
       writeValueA(…);
    } finally {
       writeValueB(…);
    }
}
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
public void writeMethod(…) {
    try {
       writeValueA(…);
    } catch(Throwable t) {
       writeValueB(…);
       throw t;
    }
    writeValueB(…);
}
```

All it does, is ensuring that `writeValueB(…);` will also get executed if `writeValueA(…);` threw an exception. If it doesn’t throw an exception, there is no difference to a plain

```
writeValueA(…);
writeValueB(…);
```

Most notably, it doesn’t bear any additional semantics regarding the Java Memory Model. There is no way in general, to implement thread safe modifications of shared data on the writer’s side without complementing efforts on the reader’s side.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your purpose correctly, you want to use `finally` in write thread to make sure that

- if a read thread can read updated `B`, then updated `A` must be available to this read thread.

This can not be achieved by `finally` key word. Even write thread write `A` and `B` in order, JVM can not gurantee read thread can get updated `A` even if it can get updated `B` without syncronization.